# javascript textarea: what was typed/pasted, and where?

Tags: javascript

How do you find out what the user typed or pasted into a textarea? For example, if they typed in `B` (or `β`) at index 1, or if they pasted `hello world\n` at index 23. I've searched a fair bit but can't find anything. Here's what I have so far, uses jQuery:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(evt){
    var index= getCaret(this); // this.selectionStart doesn't work in IE
    var key = evt.keyCode; // Wrong.
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea) for `getCaret`. The problem with `event.keyCode` is non-english keyboard layouts. I'm entirely stuck as far pasting is concerned.

If possible, I'd like to know the values before the textarea is changed - that is, from within the keydown event. I'm not sure if this can be done for pasting.

(Deletion is easier - detect `keyCode==8` for backspace and `keyCode==46` for del. If `selection.length > 0`, then the selection is removed; otherwise the character before or after is removed. In theory. There's also the case of pasting on top of a selection.)

Anything that gets any part of this closer to working in any browser is greatly appreciated. That is, how do you know:

1. the unicode string value of the typed character?
2. when a paste occurred?
3. what the text content of the paste is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your ultimate goal is here, so it's difficult to advise. However, here's some information:

When the user types a character, getting what they typed is easy enough using the `keypress` event and (assuming your event object is stored in a a variable called `evt`) using `String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode || evt.which)`.

For pasting, things are a bit trickier. The simplest thing would be to detect the paste before it has happened, store the textarea's value and after a very short time (using `window.setTimeout`) compare the new value with the old. As for detecting the paste, a lot of browsers now have the `paste` event: IE since version 5, Firefox since version 3 and WebKit browsers for a while (not sure exactly when), so you can use that for those browsers. As a fallback for other browsers you could detect Ctrl-V and Shift-Insert in a `keydown` event handler, though this is by no means foolproof since it won't fire when the user pastes using the Edit menu or the context menu in their browser.

Comment: `evt.which` has the same keyboard layout problem as `evt.keyCode`. I had considered the `setTimout` option (it would solve the layout problem too), but this requires a potentially lengthy comparison for each character typed, and can't be done before the character is entered. In any case, thanks, I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: `evt.which` is equivalent to `evt.charCode` in the `keypress` event in non-IE browsers, is supported in more browsers and reports the character code rather than the key code, so no keyboard layout problem. This page is a good reference for key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html. The `setTimeout` suggestion was only for pastes, and is not required for each character typed.